# jquery datepicker onselect event shows invalid date in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this code in my web application (see jsfiddle) ..
https://jsfiddle.net/6cgzuymh/2/

The problem is my users use both IE and chrome and this code works fine on chrome but not on IE 11.
and when I try to run the above jsfiddle on IE 11 it doesn't work. Does any body has any solution for this ?

The alert in first onselect method throws invalid date in IE but works fine in Chrome.

I have found one thing that if I remove the date format it works in IE as well, but I need dd-M-yy format as the client is from UK.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        From:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtFrom" />
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        To:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtTo" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

 $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       showAnim: "slideDown",
       dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            alert(dt); ///  <<--------------------------------  throws invalid date in IE
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
        }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       showAnim: "slideDown",
       dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
            ///$("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is wrong. Instead of `dd-M-yy` you need to write `yy-mm-dd`.

```
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showAnim: "slideDown",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  onSelect: function (selected) { }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zfgh0ce2/

You want to make a date from `new Date('04-Nov-2019')` which isn't a IETF-compliant [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) or [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iso:std:iso:8601:-1:ed-1:v1:en) date string.

-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date